# Ubuntu Software not installing

Tags: 17.04

When I try to install anything from **Ubuntu Software**, it starts up and gets to 9%, then it resets as if I never *started* the install. Does anyone know what the ***possible*** problem could be? I am running Ubuntu Zesty 17.04

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Alt+T and there use `sudo apt install PACKAGE_NAME` to install anything you like .

Alternatively use synaptics package manager

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```